# Using “reserved” codes for exit status of shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell-script, exit

I recently came across this list of [Exit Codes With Special Meanings](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) from the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide. They refer to these codes as being *reserved* and recommend that:

> According to the above table, exit codes 1-2, 126-165, and 255 have special
>   meanings, and should therefore be avoided for user-specified exit
>   parameters.

A while ago, I wrote a script which used the following exit status codes:

- 0 - success
- 1 - incorrect hostname
- 2 - invalid arguments specified
- 3 - insufficient user privileges

When I wrote the script I wasn’t aware of any special exit codes so I simply started at 1 for the first error condition, and incremented the exit status for each successive error type.

I wrote the script with the intention that at a later stage it could be called by other scripts (which could check for the non-zero exit codes).  I haven’t actually done that yet; so far I’ve only run the script from my interactive shell (Bash) and I was wondering what / if any problems could be caused by using my custom exit codes. How relevant/important is the recommendation from the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide?

I couldn’t find any corroborating advice in the Bash documentation; its section on [Exit Status](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html#Exit-Status) simply lists the exit codes used by Bash but doesn’t state that any of these are *reserved* or warn against using them for your own scripts/programs.

Comment: I, and others, consider the ABSG to be of generally low quality. In my opinion the author of the page you linked is making an unsupported assertion that the listed exit codes are reserved based, apparently, on the fact that the shell itself uses them for specific meanings. There have been attempts to create standards for scripts, none of which have had any success. The important thing is to document the error codes you choose so that consumers of your scripts (e.g. other scripts) know what to do based on them.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson If you post your comment as answer, I’d be happy to upvote it; I’ve already voted all the other answers as I found each of them to be useful. While your answer is similar in content to David King’s (and to a lesser extent Zwol’s), you state explicitly that there’s no evidence for the assertion in the ABSG quote.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I believe my comment should stay as such.

Comment: I've since discovered that the POSIX specification includes similar advice so I've added that information to my own answer (containing the results of my research since asking this question).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There have been several attempts to standardize the meanings of process exit codes.  In addition to the one you mention, I know of:

- the BSDs have [`sysexits.h`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+4.3-RELEASE&format=html) which defines meanings for values from 64 on up.
- GNU `grep` documents that exit code 0 means at least one match was found, 1 means no matches were found, and 2 means an I/O error occurred; this convention is obviously also useful for other programs for which the distinction between "nothing went wrong but I didn't find anything" and "an I/O error occurred" is meaningful.
- Many implementations of the C library function `system` use exit code 127 to indicate the program doesn't exist or failed to start.
- On Windows, [`NTSTATUS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx) codes (which are inconveniently scattered all over the 32-bit number space) may be used as exit codes, particularly the ones that indicate a process was terminated due to catastrophic misbehavior (e.g. `STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW`).

You can't count on any given program obeying any particular one of these conventions.  The only *reliable* rule is that exit code 0 is success and anything else is some sort of failure.  (Note that C89's `EXIT_SUCCESS` is *not* guaranteed to have the value zero; however, `exit(0)` is required to behave identically to `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` even if the values are not the same.)

Comment: Thanks. It was difficult to choose one answer over the others but I'm accepting this one since it answered my question while also providing a wide flavour of the the different exit codes in use (with relevant links): it deserves more than the 3 upvotes it currently has.

Answer (score 13):

No **exit code** has a special meaning, but the value in `$?` may have a special meaning.

The way Bourne Shell and ksh93 handled and forwarded exit codes and error situations to the shell variable `$?` is the problem. In contrary to what you list, only the following values for `$?` have a special meaning:

- 126 Could not execute the binary even though it exists
- 127 The specified binary does not exist
- 128 exit status was == 0 but some unspecified problem exists

In addition, there is an unspecified shell and platform-specific range of `$?` codes > 128 that is reserved for a program that was interrupted by a signal:

- Bourne Shell bash and ksh88 use 128 + signal number
- ksh93 uses 256 + signal number.

Other values do not give problems as they may be distinguished from the shell-special `$?` values.

In particular, the values 1 and 2 are not used for special conditions but are just exit codes used by builtin commands that could act the same when they are no builtins. So is seems that the pointer to the **bash scripting guide** you provided is not a good manual as it just lists codes used by bash without commenting whether a specific code is a special value that should be avoided for own scripts.

Newer versions of the Bourne Shell use `waitid()` instead of `waitpid()` to wait for the program to exit and `waitid()` (introduced 1989 for SVr4) uses a better syscall interface (similar to what UNOS used in 1980 already).

As newer Bourne Shell versions encode the **exit reason** in a separate variable `${.sh.code}` / `${.sh.codename}` than the **exit code** that is in `${.sh.status}`/ `${.sh.termsig}`, see http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/bosh.1.html, the exit code is not overloaded with special states, and, as a result from using `waitid(), the Bourne Shell now supports returning all 32 bits of the exit code – not just the low 8 bits.

BTW: be careful not to `exit(256)` or similar from a C-program or shell script, as this results in `$?` being interpreted as 0 in a classic shell.

Comment: "as this results in $? being interpreted as 0 in a classic shell." - or any shell, since it's actually not possible at the operating system level to pass more than 8 bits from exit() - the other bits of the wait status code are not controlled by the exit function; you can't fake a signal exit.

Comment: You are mistaken. `waitid()` returns all 32 bits from the exit code since 1989. You may be testing on a broken Operating system like Linux, where the kernel early destroys the upper 24 bits of the exit value in the kernel.

Comment: BTW: I made a bug report against FreeBSD and the Linux kernel for this `waitid()` bug around late May. The FreeBSD people fixed the problem within 20 hours, the Linux people are not interested in fixing their bug. ... and the Cygwin people says that they are bug by bug Linux compatible ;-)

Comment: This behavior is _required_ by the Single Unix Specification. There's a 32-bit value, yes, but that value contains an 8-bit bitfield containing the low 8 bits of the value from `_exit`. Please link the FreeBSD bug report you are referring to, maybe I'm misunderstanding the issue you describe.

Comment: _exit and exit says "only the least significant 8 bits (that is, status & 0377) shall be available to a waiting parent process."

Comment: You are mistaken again. The SUSv2 text was OK, but with SUSv3, there has been a bug introduced in the POSIX standard text that was fixed about a year ago and that will appear in issue 7 tc2 that is currently under review. As a hint: POSIX does not define things but rather describes features from existing implementations. As this feature is from SVr4, you need to check e.g. Solaris for the correct behavior.

Comment: BTW: the full 32 bit exit code is also required to appear in the `siginfo_t *` parameter of the `SIGCHLD` signal handler.

Comment: The OP tagged the question with [tag:bash] and mentioned Bash in the text of the question. Bash is a Bourne-derived shell. It does not support `${.sh.}` variables. It is true, however, that you say "Bourne" and not "Bourne-derived" (although you do include ksh93).

Comment: This answer appears to be very specific to your particular variant of some SVR4-derived Unix.  Please be clearer about what is portable and what isn't, keeping in mind that there is no such thing as "the" Bourne shell, unless you mean the one that was in V7.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson I tried to be as widely based as possible. This is why I mentioned Bourne Shell and ksh93. The OP used the tag /shell-script with means something  portable. This is why my answer includes the full spectrum of possibilities. BTW: bash is not Bourne derived but it tried to become a Bourne Shell clone in early days and then copied features from ksh88 and ksh93.

Comment: @zwol Why do you believe that my answer that covers the whole spectrum of implementations is specific to a particular implementation? It seems that you never had access to a real UNIX system. If you did, you would know that most UNIX systems include a real Bourne Shell. The latest AIX even comes with a Bourne Shell from 1986 or before. Since OpenSolaris came out in June 2005, a recent version of the Bourne Shell (e.g. with jobcontrol) has become OSS and later was made highly portable - it even works on Cygwin and is noticeable faster than the Cygwin defaultshell. It now has a history editor.

Comment: On the contrary, I believe it is you who are understating the range of variation here, especially historical variation. You make it sound like `/bin/sh` can be relied on to behave consistently wrt these special exit codes cross-platform, which is not true. (I do not *care* whether any particular system's `/bin/sh` can be said to be a "real Bourne shell". Much more important to know that none of this is in POSIX, and that most of the things you cite as "real Unix systems" don't provide a POSIX-compliant `/bin/sh` anyway.)

Comment: I recommend you to read what I wrote instead of "knowing" without reading it. People like you who believe that /bin/sh should be a POSIX shell don't know POSIX as POSIX does not deal with paths at all. But let us stop here as this has nothing to do anymore with the OPs question.

Comment: @swol i woulkd take your both answers as complementary with different point of views. with your combined answers i think most of return code values are covered.

Comment: @schily This will be my last word on the subject, but I feel it is necessary to clarify one point: I never said "`/bin/sh` should be a POSIX shell".  What I said was "[various historical Unix systems] don't provide a POSIX-compliant `/bin/sh`," which is a fact. Your answer would be fine if it admitted that the various shells you talk about are not necessarily `/bin/sh` on any given system, and therefore someone trying to write a portable shell script cannot rely on any of the behavior you describe.

Comment: @zwol What you wrote does not help anybody - it rather confuses people. What I wrote in my answer includes hints to the variations so people who carefully read my answer can write portable scripts. BTW: even on Linux, you cannot rely in a specific shell being installed as `/bin/sh`. This is why  explained all possible behavior and did not only comment the behavior of bash.

Answer (score 9):

For shell scripting, I sometimes in-source the shell equivalent of `sysexist.h` with shell-reserved exit codes (prefixed with `S_EX_`), which I've named `exit.sh`

It's basically:

```
EX_OK=0 # successful termination 
EX__BASE=64     # base value for error messages 
EX_USAGE=64     # command line usage error 
EX_DATAERR=65   # data format error 
EX_NOINPUT=66   # cannot open input 
EX_NOUSER=67    # addressee unknown 
EX_NOHOST=68    # host name unknown 
EX_UNAVAILABLE=69       # service unavailable 
EX_SOFTWARE=70  # internal software error 
EX_OSERR=71     # system error (e.g., can't fork) 
EX_OSFILE=72    # critical OS file missing 
EX_CANTCREAT=73 # can't create (user) output file 
EX_IOERR=74     # input/output error 
EX_TEMPFAIL=75  # temp failure; user is invited to retry 
EX_PROTOCOL=76  # remote error in protocol 
EX_NOPERM=77    # permission denied 
EX_CONFIG=78    # configuration error 
EX__MAX=78      # maximum listed value 

#System errors
S_EX_ANY=1      #Catchall for general errors
S_EX_SH=2       #Misuse of shell builtins (according to Bash documentation); seldom seen
S_EX_EXEC=126   #Command invoked cannot execute         Permission problem or command is not an executable
S_EX_NOENT=127  #"command not found"    illegal_command Possible problem with $PATH or a typo
S_EX_INVAL=128  #Invalid argument to exit       exit 3.14159    exit takes only integer args in the range 0 - 255 (see first footnote)                                                                                        
#128+n  Fatal error signal "n"  kill -9 $PPID of script $? returns 137 (128 + 9)                               
#255*   Exit status out of range        exit -1 exit takes only integer args in the range 0 - 255              
S_EX_HUP=129                                                                                                   
S_EX_INT=130   
#...
```

And can be generated with:

```
#!/bin/sh
src=/usr/include/sysexits.h
echo "# Generated from \"$src\"" 
echo "# Please inspect the source file for more detailed descriptions"
echo
< "$src" sed -rn 's/^#define  *(\w+)\s*(\d*)/\1=\2/p'| sed 's:/\*:#:; s:\*/::'
cat<<'EOF'

#System errors
S_EX_ANY=1  #Catchall for general errors
S_EX_SH=2   #Misuse of shell builtins (according to Bash documentation); seldom seen
S_EX_EXEC=126   #Command invoked cannot execute     Permission problem or command is not an executable
S_EX_NOENT=127  #"command not found"    illegal_command Possible problem with $PATH or a typo
S_EX_INVAL=128  #Invalid argument to exit   exit 3.14159    exit takes only integer args in the range 0 - 255 (see first footnote)
#128+n  Fatal error signal "n"  kill -9 $PPID of script $? returns 137 (128 + 9)
#255*   Exit status out of range    exit -1 exit takes only integer args in the range 0 - 255
EOF
$(which kill) -l |tr ' ' '\n'| awk '{ printf "S_EX_%s=%s\n", $0, 128+NR; }'
```

I don't use it much, though, but what I do use is a shell function that inverses error codes to their string formats. I've named it `exit2str`. Assuming you've named the above `exit.sh` generator `exit.sh.sh`, the code for `exit2str` can be generated with (`exit2str.sh.sh`) :

```
#!/bin/sh
echo '
exit2str(){
  case "$1" in'
./exit.sh.sh | sed -nEe's|^(S_)?EX_(([^_=]+_?)+)=([0-9]+).*|\4) echo "\1\2";;|p'
echo "
  esac
}"
```

I use this in the `PS1` of my interactive shell so that after each command I run, I can see its exit status and its string form (if it does have a known string form):

```
[15:58] pjump@laptop:~ 
(0=OK)$ 
[15:59] pjump@laptop:~ 
(0=OK)$ fdsaf
fdsaf: command not found
[15:59] pjump@laptop:~ 
(127=S_NOENT)$ sleep
sleep: missing operand
Try 'sleep --help' for more information.
[15:59] pjump@laptop:~ 
(1=S_ANY)$ sleep 100
^C
[15:59] pjump@laptop:~ 
(130=S_INT)$ sleep 100
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 100
[15:59] pjump@laptop:~ 
(148=S_TSTP)$
```

To get these, you need an insourcable for the exit2str function:

```
$ ./exit2str.sh.sh > exit2str.sh #Place this somewhere in your PATH
```

and then use it in your `~/.bashrc` to save and translate the exit code on each command prompt and display it your prompt (`PS1`):

```
    # ...
    . exit2str.sh
PROMPT_COMMAND='lastStatus=$(st="$?"; echo -n "$st"; str=$(exit2str "$st") && echo "=$str"); # ...'
    PS1="$PS1"'\n($lastStatus)\$'
    # ...
```

It's quite handy for observing how some programs follow the exit code conventions and some don't, for learning about exit code conventions, or just for being able to see what's going on more readily.
Having been using it for some time, I can say that many system-oriented shell scripts do follow the conventions. `EX_USAGE` is particularly quite common, although other codes, not much. I try to follow the conventions from time to time, although there's always `$S_EX_ANY` (1) for lazy people (I am one).

Comment: I do wonder if there's anything like a mapping between an errno code and an exit code to use if the error reported with that errno code results in an error exit. I might need to come up with some reasonable mapping.

Comment: Wow! I wasn't expecting such an elaborate answer. I'll definitely try that out as a good way to see how different commands behave. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The best reference I could find was this: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

According to this:

`1` is a general catchall for errors, and I've always seen it used for user defined errors.

`2` is for misuse of shell built ins, such as a syntax error

To answer your question directly your script will be fine using the reserved error codes, it will function as expected assuming you handle the error based on the error code = 1/2/3.

However, it would possibly be confusing if you encounter anyone who knows and uses the reserved error codes, which seems quite rare.

Another option available to you is to echo the error if there is one and then exit, assuming your script follows the Linux convention of "no news is good news" and echo's nothing on success.

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
    echo "Error type"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

As long as you document your exit codes so that you remember them a year from now when you have to come back and tweak the script you'll be fine.  The idea of "reserved exit codes" doesn't really apply anymore other than to say it's customary to use `0` as a success code and anything else as a failure code.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answers I’ve received (it was difficult to pick one over the others), it **isn’t harmful** to indicate certain types of errors by using an exit code that Bash also uses.  Bash (or any other Unix shell) won’t do anything special (such as running exception handlers) if a user script exits with one of these error codes.

It seems that the author of the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide agrees with the BSD attempts to standardise exit codes (`sysexits.h`) and is simply *recommending* that when users write shell scripts, they don’t specify exit codes that conflict with pre-defined exit codes already in use, i.e., they restrict their custom exit codes to the 50 available status codes in the range 64-113.

I appreciate the idea (and the rationale) but I’d have preferred if the author was more explicit that it’s not harmful to ignore the advice – aside from cases where the consumer of a script is checking for errors such as the cited example of 127 (`command not found`).

### Relevant POSIX specifications

I researched what POSIX has to say about exit codes and the POSIX specification seems to concur with the author of the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide. I’ve quoted the relevant POSIX specifications (emphasis mine):

[Exit Status for Commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_02)

> Each command has an exit status that can influence the behavior of other shell commands. The exit status of commands that are not utilities is documented in this section. The exit status of the standard utilities is documented in their respective sections.
>
> If a command is not found, the exit status shall be 127. If the command name is found, but it is not an executable utility, the exit status shall be 126. **Applications that invoke utilities without using the shell should use these exit status values to report similar errors.**
>
> If a command fails during word expansion or redirection, its exit status shall be greater than zero.
>
> Internally, for purposes of deciding whether a command exits with a non-zero exit status, the shell shall recognize the entire status value retrieved for the command by the equivalent of the wait() function WEXITSTATUS macro (as defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2008). When reporting the exit status with the special parameter '?', the shell shall report the full eight bits of exit status available. The exit status of a command that terminated because it received a signal shall be reported as greater than 128.

[The `exit` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_21_18)

> As explained in other sections, certain exit status values have been **reserved** for special uses and **should** be used by applications only for those purposes:
>
> - `126` – A file to be executed was found, but it was not an executable utility.
> - `127` – A utility to be executed was not found.
> - `>128` – A command was interrupted by a signal.

### Further information

For what it’s worth, I was able to verify all but one of the list of [Exit Codes With Special Meanings](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html). This table of exit codes is useful as it provides more details – and examples of how to generate the error codes documented in the [Bash reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html#Exit-Status).

#### Attempt to generate exit status of 128

Using Bash versions 3.2.25 and 4.2.46, I tried to throw a `128 Invalid argument to exit` error but each time I received a 255 (Exit status out of range).  E.g., if `exit 3.14159` is executed as part of a shell script or in an interactive child shell, the shell exits with a code of `255`:

```
$ exit 3.14159
exit
bash: exit: 3.14159: numeric argument required
```

For even more fun, I also tried running a simple C program but in this case, it seems that the `exit(3)` function simply converted the float to an int (3 in this case) before exiting:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
    exit(3.14159);
}
```