# Why is "Doing an exit 130 is not the same as dying of SIGINT"?

Tags: bash, shell, signals, exit-status

From Stéphane Chazelas's reply at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/230568

> Ideally, we'd want to report to our parent that we died of a SIGINT
>   (so that if it's another bash script for instance, that bash script is
>   also interrupted). **Doing an exit 130 is not the same as dying of
>   SIGINT** (though some shells will set $? to same value for both cases),
>   however it's often used to report a death by SIGINT (on systems where
>   SIGINT is 2 which is most).
>
> However **for bash, ksh93 or FreeBSD sh, that doesn't work. That 130
>   exit status is not considered as a death by SIGINT** and a parent script
>   would not abort there.

1. Regarding "Doing an exit 130 is not the same as dying of SIGINT",
   what are the differences between them?
2. Why is it that "for bash, ksh93 or FreeBSD sh, that doesn't work. That
   130 exit status is not considered as a death by SIGINT"?

From Bash manual:

> When a command terminates on a fatal signal whose number is N, Bash uses the value 128+N as the exit status

The signal number of SIGINT is 2, so the exit status of a command
    terminating on SIGINT is 130.
So it seems to me that doing an exit 130 is the same as dying of SIGINT, and that
    130 exit status is  considered as a death by SIGINT.

Thanks.

Comment: See [Default exit code when process is terminated?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/99112)

Answer (score 16):

The 130 (128+SIGINT) you see in `$?` after the last command died of a SIGINT is a simplified representation of its exit status made by some shells like `bash`. Other shells will use different representations (like 256+signum in ksh93, 128+256+signum in yash, textual representations like `sigint` or `sigquit+core` in `rc`/`es`). See [Default exit code when process is terminated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/99112) for more details on that.

A process can wait for its child process and query its status:

- if it was stopped (with which signal)
- if it was resumed
- if it was killed (with which signal)
- if it has *trapped* (for *ptrace*d processes)
- if it dumped a *core*
- if it exited normally with the `_exit()` system call (with which exit code)

To do that, they use one of the `wait()`, `waitpid()`, `waitid()` (see also obsolete `wait3()`, `wait4()`) or a handler on the SIGCHLD system call.

Those system calls return all that information above. (Except for `waitid()` on some system, only the lowest 8 bits of the number passed to `_exit()` for child that terminate normally are available though).

But `bash` (and most Bourne-like and csh-like shells) bundle all that information in a 8 bit number for `$?` (`$?` is the lowest 8 bits of the exit code for processes that terminate normally, and 128+signum it it was killed or suspended or trapped, all the other information is not available). So obviously, there's some information being lost. In particular, through `$?` alone, one can't tell if a process did a `_exit(130)` or died of a SIGINT.

`bash` knows when a process is being killed obviously. For example when background processes are killed, you see:

```
[1]+  Interrupt               sleep 20
```

But in `$?`, it doesn't give you enough information to tell whether it was killed by SIGINT or it called `_exit(130)`.

Since most shells do that transformation, applications know better than doing `_exit(number_greater_than_127)` for anything but reporting a death by signal though.

Still if a process does a `_exit(130)`, the process waiting for that process will detect that that process terminated normally, not that it was killed by a signal. In C, `WIFEXITED()` will return *true*, `WIFSIGNALED()` will return false.

`bash` itself will not consider the process as having died of a SIGINT (even though it lets you think it might have through `$?` containing the same value as if it had died of a SIGINT).

So, that will not trigger the special handling of SIGINT that `bash` does. In a script, both `bash` and the currently running command in the script will receive a SIGINT upon `^C` (as they're both in the same process group).

`bash` dies upon receiving SIGINT only if the command it is waiting for also died of a SIGINT (the idea being that if for instance in your script, you run vi or less and use ^C to abort something there which doesn't make `vi`/`less` die, your script doesn't die upon returning quitting `vi`/`less` later on).

If that command `bash` is waiting for does a `_exit(130)` in a handler of SIGINT, `bash` will not die upon that SIGINT (it will not consider itself as having been interrupted because it doesn't believe the child has been interrupted).

That's why when you want to report a *death by SIGINT*, that *you have indeed been interrupted even though you are actually doing some extra processing upon receiving that signal in a handler*, you should not do a `_exit(130)`, but actually kill yourself with SIGINT (after having restored the default handler for SIGINT). In a shell, that's with:

```
trap '
  extra processing
  trap - INT # restore SIGINT handler
  kill -s INT "$$" # report to the parent that we have indeed been
                   # interrupted
  ' INT
```

Comment: Interestingly, Jörg Schilling's `bosh` does not conflate the exit code and exit status into a single variable. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/242116/5132

Comment: Any idea on how to do the `kill -s INT "$$"` part in a python script? I.e., how do I "kill myself" / "report" the parent that I was interrupted by a signal?

Comment: @MestreLion I've described how to do that in Python over on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74525682/674039). TL;DR you simply don't handle the default `KeyboardInterrupt` exception (or if you do catch it, just reraise it after your cleanup actions). No messing around with [`signal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) module is necessary.