# I have if else question but I am not sure the answer is true?

Tags: shell, echo, test

I am running this on Linux:

```
$ number=4
$ test $number -eq 4
$ echo $?
0
$ test $number -lt 2
$ echo $?
1
```

Are the results (0 and 1) true ?

Comment: Are you asking if two opposite values are the same? O.o

Comment: @muru No I mean are results true ?

Comment: But shouldn't the answer be 1 if the result is true?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2933843/2072269

Comment: See also [What are the shell’s control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216) (specifically [terdon’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216#159514), section A.2) and  [Using “reserved” codes for exit status of shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/242111/80216).

Comment: If any of the answers solves your issue, please consider ["accepting" the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). This is the best way to show gratitude on this site.  Accepting an answer not only marks the question as resolved, but also signals to _future readers_ that the accepted answer actually solved the issue.  More information about this is available here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

On Unix systems, utilities return a zero exit-status if what they did went well, if it succeeded without errors etc.  If a utility fails, it returns a non-zero exit status.

This way, it's possible to tell a user with the exit-status what when wrong (see e.g. the "EXIT VALUES" or similar section of some manuals, for example the manual of `rsync`).  In short, if the operation succeeded, the exit-status is zero and if it's not zero, it failed and the exit-status may say why it failed.

The `test` utility, which you use, follow this pattern in that if a comparison succeeded (it's "true"), it returns zero.  If the comparison (or whatever operation it carries out) fails (it's "false"), it returns a non-zero exit-status.

The `if` keyword takes a utility and acts on its exit-status.  If the utility returns a zero exit-status, it takes the default branch, otherwise it takes the `else` branch:

```
if test 4 -eq 3; then
    echo 4 is 3
else
    echo 4 is not 3
fi
```

`if` can take any utility:

```
if grep -q 'secret' file.txt; then
    echo file.txt contains secret
else
    echo file.txt does not contain secret
fi
```

```
if mkdir mydir; then
    echo created directory mydir
else
    echo failed to create directory mydir
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 3):

By convention, `0` means the operation was a success and anything other than 0 is an error. So, if `$?` is `0`, then the test was successful and if it is not `0`, for example if it is `1`, the test failed.

You can see this a bit more clearly perhaps if you run this:

```
$ number=4
$ if test $number -eq 4; then echo "YES ($?)"; else echo "NO ($?)"; fi
YES (0)
$ if test $number -lt 2; then echo "YES ($?)"; else echo "NO ($?)"; fi
NO (1)
```

Comment: Thank you @terdon you explained clearly.

Comment: With the caveat, of course, that in `(())`, booleans are C-style (0 is falsey)

Answer (score 0):

The shell is not `C`. In `C` 0 is false, everything else is true. In the shell 0 is true/success, everything else is false. This is because there are many ways to fail, but one way to succeed.

Specifically from the info page, of test.

```
Exit status:

 0 if the expression is true,
 1 if the expression is false,
 2 if an error occurred.
```

Comment: Thank you so much you explained well.